# how to get a time difference between two dates in ("Y-m-d H:i:s") format?

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to get the difference between two date-times and return it as a minute. Date & Time are taken in date("Y-m-d H:i:s") format. But it seem i can't get it right. I did it

```
$time=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$time=date("2014-01-13 08:18:25");

$interval = $time->diff($login_time);
$elapsed = $interval->format(%i minutes);
echo $elapsed;
```

And This is showing a massage 
 "Call to a member function diff() on a non-object"

As I am not good enough with date formatting. So Please help me.

What is the way to go about this?

Comment: Well, first of all, `$time` is not an object, as it says. It is merely a string containg the current date. Also a duplicate, see accepted answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: Before putting question here do googling

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2013-01-13 04:10:58');
$datediff = $date1->diff(new DateTime('2013-09-11 10:25:00'));
echo $datediff->i;
```

For more details see this link : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: If difference is more than 59 minutes, result will be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Get **difference is minutes** between two dates:

```php
$now     = new DateTime;
$before  = new DateTime('2014-01-10 08:18:25');
$diff    = $now->diff($before);
$elapsed = $diff->days * 24 * 60 + $diff->h * 60 + $diff->i;
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/88580)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code for getting time in all expected parameter.

> $time1=date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
>      
> $time2=date("2014-01-13 08:18:25");
>
> $seconds = strtotime($time1) - strtotime($start);
>
> $year = floor(($seconds)/(60*60*24*365)); 
> $months = floor($seconds /
>   86400 / 30 ); 
> $week    = floor($seconds / 604800); 
> $days    =
>   floor($seconds / 86400); 
> $hours   = floor(($seconds - ($days * 86400))
>   / 3600);
>  $minutes = floor(($seconds - ($days * 86400) - ($hours *
>   3600))/60); 
> $seconds = floor(($seconds - ($days * 86400) - ($hours *
>   3600) - ($minutes*60)));