# Minutes between two DateTimes in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval, date-math

I am trying to get the number of minutes between two DateTimes in PHP:

```
$time = new DateTime($dateString);
$now = new DateTime;
$diff = $time->diff($now);

echo $diff->format('%m');
```

The result is always 0, although the DateTimes are several hours apart.
How would I do this the right way?

Comment: posible duplicate **http://stackoverflow.com/q/21088739/67332** ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%m` is for months. Minutes is `%i`:

```
echo $diff->format('%i');
```

Comment: So much for my reading skills... ^^

Comment: You can see all formats in the PHP documentation here: http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: One question though: does this return the TOTAL number of minutes? Or the number of minutes MODULO the hours? (if you know what I mean)

Comment: It's return the number of minutes MODULO the hours.

Comment: It would be modulus hours. So if it is over 59 minutes you would need to factor in hours as well. You could check to see if hours is over zero and, if so, multiply that times 60 to get your total minutes.

Comment: @JohnConde Wouldn't it be a waste of resources to check if hours is over zero, and THEN multiply it? You could just say `hours * 60 + minutes`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Certainly :)

Answer (score 2):

**Total number of minutes** between 2 datetimes:

```php
$diff = (new DateTime($string))->diff(new DateTime); # PHP >= 5.4.0
#$diff = date_diff(date_create($string), date_create()); # PHP >= 5.3.0
$minutes = ($diff->days * 24 + $diff->h) * 60 + $diff->i;
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/94816)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would keep it simple and use the difference between timestamps/60:-

```
$minutes = ($date2->getTimestamp() - $date1->getTimestamp())/60;
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/eq79k).